# Pass custom class instance to JAX-WS service method

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to pass a custom object into a JAX-WS service method. Nothing I do seems to work.

How do I get an instance of this trivial class

```
public class User
{
  // Private instance variables
  public String firstname;
  public String lastname;

  public User() {}

//  // Constructor for a new user doesn't have an ID parameter
  public User (String firstname, String lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }

  // Get & Set Methods
  /* Returns the user's last name */
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastname;
  }

  /* Sets the user's last name */
  public void setLastName(String newLastName) {
    lastname = newLastName;
  }

  /* Returns the user's first name */
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstname;
  }

  /* Sets the user's first name */
  public void setFirstName(String newfirstname) {
    firstname = newfirstname;
  }
}
```

To be passed into a web service method, like so:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "UserService",
            endpointInterface = "IUserService",
            targetNamespace = "http://bioflip.org")
public class UserService implements IUserService
{   
    @Override
    public String getUserName(User user) 
    {
        return user.getFirstName() + " "  + user.getLastName();
    }
}
```

Here is the service interface:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://bioflip.org")
public interface IUserService 
{
    @WebMethod
    String getUserName(User user);
}
```

My service doesn't deploy on Tomcat EE 7. What is wrong? Also, any good tutorials on a topic (that is NOT a hello world tutorial, which seem to be everywhere and are super useless) would be highly appreciated.

The error part of the stack trace:

```
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/Dmitry/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BioFlipServiceTest' did not find a matching property.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: ********************************************************************************
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: OpenEJB http://openejb.apache.org/
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Startup: Thu Sep 11 17:16:19 EDT 2014
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Copyright 1999-2013 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Version: 4.7.0
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Build date: 20140810
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Build time: 12:40
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: ********************************************************************************
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: openejb.home = /Users/Dmitry/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: openejb.base = /Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFO: Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@1a9a098e
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFO: Succeeded in installing singleton service
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory init
INFO: openejb configuration file is '/Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/conf/openejb.xml'
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=My DataSource, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=My Unmanaged DataSource, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=My Singleton Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Singleton Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=My Stateful Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateful Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=My Stateless Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentsResolver loadFrom
WARNING: File error: <Deployments dir="apps/"> - Does not exist: /Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/apps
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.system.apps=true'
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: openejb
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Using openejb.deploymentId.format '{ejbName}'
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb openejb/Deployer: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb openejb/ConfigurationInfo: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:19 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb MEJB: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=MEJB)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "openejb" loaded.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Resource(id=My DataSource)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator$TomEEDataSource readOnly
INFO: Disabling testOnBorrow since no validation query is provided
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Resource(id=My Unmanaged DataSource)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator$TomEEDataSource readOnly
INFO: Disabling testOnBorrow since no validation query is provided
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Container(id=My Singleton Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Container(id=My Stateful Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.core.stateful.SimplePassivater init
INFO: Using directory /var/folders/l4/p46wd9cx2yd85xyq1jrm2k840000gn/T for stateful session passivation
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Container(id=My Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: openejb
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.jndiname.format={deploymentId}{interfaceType.openejbLegacyName}'
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=openejb/DeployerBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/Deployer!org.apache.openejb.assembler.Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=openejb/ConfigurationInfoBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/ConfigurationInfo!org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.cmd.ConfigurationInfo) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/ConfigurationInfo) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=MEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/MEJB!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/MEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=My Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=MEJB, container=My Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, container=My Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=My Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=MEJB, container=My Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, container=My Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler deployMBean
INFO: Deployed MBean(openejb.user.mbeans:application=openejb,group=org.apache.openejb.assembler.monitoring,name=JMXDeployer)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=openejb)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:20 PM org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager initServer
INFO: Creating ServerService(id=cxf)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager initServer
INFO: Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO:   ** Bound Services **
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager printRow
INFO:   NAME                 IP              PORT  
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO: -------
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO: Ready!
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2932 ms
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener bindResource
INFO: Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.55 (1.7.0)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: /Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ROOT
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "/Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ROOT" loaded.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: /Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ROOT
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
INFO: Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@1a9a098e
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer validateInjectionPoints
INFO: All injection points were validated successfully.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 81 ms.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=/Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ROOT)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /BioFlipServiceTest
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: /Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/BioFlipServiceTest
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "/Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/BioFlipServiceTest" loaded.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: /Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/BioFlipServiceTest
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
INFO: Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@1a9a098e
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer validateInjectionPoints
INFO: All injection points were validated successfully.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 8 ms.
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=/Users/Dmitry/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/BioFlipServiceTest)
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsService afterApplicationCreated
SEVERE: Error deploying CXF webservice for servlet UserService
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.Utils.getMethodXJTA(Utils.java:294)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:375)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:329)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:365)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:329)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.begin(JAXBContextInitializer.java:183)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.visitOperation(ServiceModelVisitor.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.walk(ServiceModelVisitor.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:325)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:490)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:697)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:214)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfEndpoint.doServiceCreate(CxfEndpoint.java:101)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.pojo.PojoEndpoint.<init>(PojoEndpoint.java:89)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.pojo.PojoWsContainer.createEndpoint(PojoWsContainer.java:70)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.pojo.PojoWsContainer.createEndpoint(PojoWsContainer.java:45)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.start(CxfWsContainer.java:50)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfService.createPojoWsContainer(CxfService.java:102)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsService.afterApplicationCreated(WsService.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.TomeeJaxWsService.afterApplicationCreated(TomeeJaxWsService.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$MethodInvocation.invoke(ObserverManager.java:399)
    at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$InvocationList.invoke(ObserverManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.doFire(ObserverManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.fireEvent(ObserverManager.java:99)
    at org.apache.openejb.loader.SystemInstance.fireEvent(SystemInstance.java:134)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.afterStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1651)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Sep 11, 2014 5:16:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 11, 2014 5:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 952 ms
```

Comment: Post the exception logged when trying to deploy this service in your tomcat installation.

Comment: Ok, I posted the error.

Comment: Are you sure this is the entire log, isn't there a *Caused by* part?

Comment: This is the error I see in the console when I try to run the code on the Tomcat EE through eclipse. Am I looking in the wrong place? I didn't post the entire thing, just the part that had the error. I posted the entire thing now.